# Idiom: use of "all things X"

Tags: idioms, expressions, idioms-in-context

While understanding the general meaning of "all things X" ("All Things Electronic", for instance), I'm having some issue putting it into a sentence.

Would you rather use (I can't really explain my issue without examples, but would be happy to edit this based on your suggestions):

- "Please let me know if you have any questions all things electronic"
- "Please let me know if you have any questions **on** all things electronic"
- "Please let me know if you have any questions **on** all things electronic **related**"

Or another way?

I guess my issue comes from not knowing precisely what "all things" implies.

Comment: The first one does not work. It needs a word like "on" or "about".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase "all things electronic" functions like a noun.  So consider

> Do you have a question cats?
>
> Do you have a question on cats?
>
> Do you have a question on cats related?

I'd say the middle one was the best. In the same way I'd use

> ...questions on all things electronic

You could also say

> ...questions about all things electronic

> ... questions related to all things electronic