# Question about "When it comes to all things"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, expressions

I recently came across the expression "**When it comes to all things**" and I'm a little confused as to its correct meaning. I did some research and found several examples of using this expression. Here are some of them:

> *Omaha’s Christine McGuigan Photography NAILS IT **when it comes to all things** wedding photography.*
>
> *We have to take the long view **when it comes to all things** working together for our good.*

> ***When it Comes to All Things** 'Pneumatic', You Certainly Came to the Right Place*

I'm particularly confused as to why the words "**all things**" are used in this expression.

If I omitted these words and used only "**when it comes to**" as shown below would the sentences have the same meaning?

> *Omaha’s Christine McGuigan Photography NAILS IT **when it comes to** wedding photography.*

> *We have to take the long view **when it comes to** working together for our good.*

> ***When it Comes to** 'Pneumatic', You Certainly Came to the Right Place*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a "known" expression, so let's break it up.

There are two idioms here, the first "when it comes to X" and the second "all things X".

#### "When it comes to X"

> When considering some particular person, thing, or action. [Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/when+it+comes+to)

#### "all things X"

This is the tricky part, where the whole phrase acts as a noun. Let's rephrase your sentence:

> We have to take the long view **when it comes to all things** working together for our good.
>
> We have to take the long view **when it comes to all things that are** working together for our good.

> **When it Comes to All Things** 'Pneumatic', You Certainly Came to the Right Place
>
> **When it Comes to All Things that are** 'Pneumatic', You Certainly Came to the Right Place

> Omaha’s Christine McGuigan Photography NAILS IT **when it comes to all things** wedding photography.
>
> Omaha’s Christine McGuigan Photography NAILS IT **when it comes to all things that are** wedding photography.

And yes there is a difference when you omit this. Leaving the phrase there gives context on "all things" and dissolves any ambuigity.

**Related**:

> [Idiom use of "all things X"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/269175/idiom-use-of-all-things-x)